# Search for specific in-reply-to header in gmail api

Tags: api, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I'm using [GMail Api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) and I would like to query users messages if they have a message with header

> `In-Reply-To: <specificMessageID@service.com>`

I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

I guess method should be [`messages.list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) but there are no query like: `rfc822msginreplyto:`

If there is no such possibility do you think, it is good practice to fetch last 100 users emails and check it manually?

Comment: I don't think Gmail, nor the Gmail API, has this functionality. It can't be found in the [**Search Operators list**](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en).

Comment: Okay thanks for your answer, so I guess the only option is to manually fetch last emails.

Comment: I would [**list messages**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) with `q = rfc822msgid:msgid@example.com` and then [**get the thread**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/get) of that message to see what the replies are.

Answer (score 0):

You could [**list messages**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) with `q = rfc822msgid:msgid@example.com` and then [**get the thread**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/get) of that message to see what the replies are.

Answer (score -1):

[Message.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) returns a list of [Users.messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource)

Message.list does have a q method.

> q string Only return messages matching the specified query. Supports
>   the same query format as the Gmail search box. For example,
>   "from:someuser@example.com rfc822msgid: is:unread". Parameter cannot
>   be used when accessing the api using the gmail.metadata scope

So you can test it by searching in gmail itself if you can get it to work there it should work VIA the api.

> In-Reply-To: <XXX@gmail.com>

I tested that and it appears to work.

I am not sure which client library you are using but most of them have an optional parameters option when creating the request that will allow you to add the q parameter.

Update:

Test your query from Gmail Search

[image]

The request you send must be accurate you must not add spaces on the end or remove the space after :

> In-Reply-To: <dddi@gmail.com>

Example:

> https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?access_token=XXXX&q=In-Reply-To:%20%3Cdddi@gmail.com%3E

Response

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "152377f1efe8d069",
   "threadId": "152376d14b187e44"
  }
 ],
 "resultSizeEstimate": 1
}
```

Using try me at the bottom on of the page.

[image]

Comment: I've tested this and unfortunately doesn't get me any result. My query is `In-Reply-To:CAFs+qjWz8oGLhFK9GzoXAguuJrbNMGy9cEXqJ987v8XeofZOrA@mail.gmail.com`

Comment: You are missing the space after the ':'   Did you test this using the google Drive Search form?   I tested it both in drive and the api it works

Comment: I've tested both `In-Reply-To:id@s.com` and `In-Reply-To: id@s.com` and still get no results. It would be perfect solution but it does not seems to work form me. I use: [https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list](Google APIs Explorer) and result is resultSizeEstimate:0; Again query is `In-Reply-To: CAA5K+n8OeqXn-pcQXGEvt6a7iMKC16w_jwP8fndrwKOLqy-gEA@mail.gmail.com` and I know that i have message with this header in inbox for sure.

Comment: You are missing the "<" and ">" in the email address.  Please test this in Gmail search.   Then copy the string its much easer.

Comment: Ok I see. You are using actually e-mail address and I'm using [MessageID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-ID) from header. Unfortunately email address give me only 1 message for my account witch is not that I was looking for. And I have to be specific about message ID.

Comment: A messageid is a single email.  You should just use message.get.   If you are trying to find multiple emails with in a thread it doesn't work that way. Each message is going to have its own message id.   and the rfc822 msgid is not the same as the gmail message id.

Comment: I know that. I'm just trying to get answers to any email in a thread. I end up doing it like this: getting threadId I'm interested in, fetch every messages from thread (and get theirs MessageIDs), loop again through messages and look for header `In-Reply-To:` pointed to any MessageID's I just fetched. It works fine. I want to be specific about a thread so if someone reply to another mail I won't get that messages.

Comment: Yeah I don't think it works like that you cant search thread based.  Once you fetch all of the emails you can search the header after its downloaded.    I think I will add an issue that we should be able to search emails in threads.   But I am not sure how that's going to work when each email has a different id.

Comment: Ok you are right. I'll ignore Message ID and just fetch messges inside thread. Then just loop through them if sender is not owner of account (From header != your.email). That should do the trick. Simplest solution for me.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solution is best.